# Is there a way I can easily identify a selector in external stylesheet in css without going through all the code line by line? in html css

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have downloaded bootstrap theme and am trying to style it using the external stylesheet. But am finding it difficult to identify the stylesheet applied to that particular element even though I identify the selector name but still. I need go through all the entire code searching for it line by line.

Comment: Most browser developer tools allow you to inspect an element to see which css classes have been applied. And they also let you live edit the css to understand how your customization might affect the element and page.  See: [View and change CSS](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/)

Answer (score 2):

Put your custom stylesheet below the theme's stylesheets at head section, and override the styles using identified selectors.